# Tela do SMFL transparente

Tags: c++, codeblocks, lib

Acabei de instalar o SFML, fiz tudo corretamente ao que parece, pois o programa não indica erros e repeti o processo cuidadosamente 3 vezes no codeblock e duas vezes no visual studio (2017). Eu consigo compilar o programa que é utilizado como exemplar no site:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa deveria mostrar um círculo verde, entretanto está abrindo uma janela do transparente

[image: Janela ao lado do compilador com o título SFML...]

Alguém sabe a causa disso e como consertar? Se poderem ajudar, agradeço.